# Webpack: expressing module dependency

Tags: requirejs, amd, webpack

I'm trying to `require` the [bootstrap-webpack](https://github.com/bline/bootstrap-webpack) module in my webpacked application.

It appears to need jQuery, since the bundled javascript then throws the following:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**

How do I go about specifying to webpack that jQuery is a dependency for the bootstrap-webpack module, to fix this issue? It feels like it should be trivial, but I've been struggling to figure it out.

I've tried adding:

```
"jquery": "latest"
```

to the dependecies in  the bootstrap-webpack's `package.json`, but this didn't work. The [documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/) is incomplete, and I can't seem to find much about this issue. It should be trivial, right? Help!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

**Use the ProvidePlugin**: It scans the source code for the given identifier and replaces it with a reference to the given module, just like it has been required.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
       })
    ]
};
```

**Use the [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader)**: It provides the possibility to prepend preparations like `require()` statements.

```
// webpack.config.js
{
    ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "imports?jQuery=jquery" }
        ]
    }
}
```

In that case you need to run `npm install imports-loader --save` before.

Comment: **imports-loader** doesn't seem to work while using grunt-webpack.

Comment: Using the provide plugin works well along with the bootstrap-webpack module.

Comment: Thx, works using `webpack.ProvidePlugin` with native npm bootstrap and jQuery installation

Answer (score 10):

Via [this github issue](https://github.com/gowravshekar/bootstrap-webpack/issues/7).

Install `expose-loader` and add `require('expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery');` to your main entry point just before you require webpack-bootstrap.

This will set jQuery on the window so any file can get at it.  Be careful with this method all files will then have access to that version of jQuery regardless of whether it was explicitly required.

Comment: Weirdly, I didn't need this on OSX, but on Windows I found that this was required to get things to work.