# webpack CommonJS backbone and underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, webpack

I'd like to use Backbone with webpack in the CommonJS style, but I need to understand how to:

- Tell webpack that Backbone depends on underscore
- Prevent them from automatically defaulting to AMD

It seems like `imports-loader` might be the answer. Do I want something like this in my configuration?

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: require.resolve('_'),
            loader: 'imports?_=underscore,define=>false'
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('backbone'),
            loader: 'imports?define=>false'
        }
    ]
},
```

Also, will this make it so I don't have to do `var _ = require('underscore');` before I do `var Backbone = require('backbone');` everywhere?

My question might be deemed a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749045/webpack-expressing-module-dependency), but I hope to get a little more clarification than provided in the accepted answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've installed backbone via npm, it should be required via CommonJS. When installed, NPM modules also automatically retrieve and install their dependencies in their own `node_modules` folder, which means you don't have to worry about providing underscore to backbone.